# "It is" + present simple

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, verbs, past-participles

> If **it is build** here, it will be next to a large housing estate.

Can anyone tell me if "it is build" in the above sentence is correct?

And if so, why isn't it in the form "it is" + past participle? Shouldn't the correct form be "If it is *built* here..."?

Comment: You know that it's wrong, so why ask the question? This isn't a real question. Assume the writer made a typo or had a brain fart; assume the copy editor missed the typo. Correct it in your mind. Don't assume that everything you see in print is correct, even if it's written by a native speaker.

Comment: @BillFranke: Apparently, he doesn't know that it is wrong. I don't understand why you assume that he does. He *thinks* it may be wrong, but he isn't sure, so he asks for confirmation.

Comment: @Cerebrus: I assumed that because he asked if the correct form wasn't "If it is built here...". Maybe you're right and I assumed too much.

Comment: @Cerebrus and also BillFranke You also assume that mt22 is male though there's nothing on the profile to indicate that. Don't forget that women can be just as confused about language as men...

Comment: @Mynamite: the default pronoun in English is (or at least used to be) *he*. This has nothing to do with misogyny or feminism; it's just a convention, same as "righty tighty lefty loosy", or what side of the street you drive on.

Comment: @Marthaª  :) My comment was tongue in cheek because of the other assumptions that were going on. However, it's a convention that exists precisely because of male-dominated societies, so I would argue that its origins certainly do have to do with arrogance and self centredness if not actual misogyny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a simple error, possibly a typo. It should definitely be *built*.